# Retreiving and displaying a value from a native Cordova plugin in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to retrieve an identification number from my native SDK plugin I have built in Cordova but I can't see to get it no matter what I try. I have a native Android application that gets the number from the device but the code doesn't translate to Cordova directly.

Working Android Code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Device = SdkForAndroid.getInstance(this);

    // First, we test if the device was already initialized. 
    if (!Device.isInitialized()) {

        Log.i(TAG, "mobile device not initialized yet");

        initializeSDK();

    } else {

        // if we already initialized, show the Secured Objects we got

        //Log.i(TAG, "device is initialized. deviceId: " + mobileDevice.getDeviceId());
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceId);
        textView.setText("" + Device.getDeviceId());
    }
}

Private void initializeSDK() {
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String deviceId = Device.initialize();//hidden sdk code

                Log.i(TAG, "initialized SDK, deviceId = " + deviceId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to initialize SDK", e);
            } 
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Cordova code:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    if (action.equals("initializeSDK")) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        isInitialized();
                    }
                });
            return true;
        }
protected void isInitialized(){
                  Device = SdkForAndroid.getInstance(cordova.getActivity());
                  try{
                        if (!Device.isInitialized()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "mobile device not initialized yet");
                            initSDK();
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "mobile device is initialized. deviceId: " + Device.getDeviceId());
                        }
                        this.callbackContext.success(mobileDevice.getDeviceId());
                  } catch (Exception e){
                        this.callbackContext.error("Error");
                  }

}

protected void initSDK(){
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                    try{
                        String deviceId = mobileDevice.initialize()
                            //hidden sdk code
                        Log.i(TAG, "initialized SDK, deviceId = " + deviceId);
                                callbackContext.success(deviceId);
                            } catch (Exception e){
                                Log.e(TAG, "failed to initialize SDK", e);
                                callbackContext.error("Error");
                            }
                }
            });
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
    initializeSDK: function (success, fail) {
        cordova.exec(success, fail, 'BlueIDplugin', 'initializeSDK', []);
    }
};
```

Ionic appcomponent.ts

```
 initiateSDK(){

    this.BlueIdPlugin.initializeSDK(
      function(success){
        console.log(deviceId);
      },
      function(fail){
        console.log("Error getting device id")
      }
    )

    this.BlueIdPlugin.initializeSDK();
    console.log(this.BlueIdPlugin.getDeviceId());
  }
```

I think I'm linking the code correctly as the SDK is initialised with my console log. The problem is that I cannot get the deviceId to display. I'm really unsure about how to interact with the problem in ionic itself, I believe the problem actual lives there as I'm not calling the success callback correctly. Please help! :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my package name at the top of my plugin. It had an extra folder directory at the end so the plugin wasn't actually connecting to the Ionic application.

So essentially the

```
   <feature name="IDplugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="IdCordovaPlugin.IDplugin"/>
   </feature>
```

Must match the package name at the top of your Cordova java plugin

```
package IdCordovaPlugin;
```

A really silly mistake on my part, found later by debugging via logcat.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are calling the success callback twice, even if device is not initialised:

```
this.callbackContext.success(mobileDevice.getDeviceId());
```

This results in callbackContext being invoked twice, which Cordova does not allow (unless you request it explicitly). So try this:

Cordova code:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    if (action.equals("initializeSDK")) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        isInitialized();
                    }
                });
            return true;
        }
protected void isInitialized(){
    Device = SdkForAndroid.getInstance(cordova.getActivity());
    try{
        if (!Device.isInitialized()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "mobile device not initialized yet");
            initSDK();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "mobile device is initialized. deviceId: " + Device.getDeviceId());
            this.callbackContext.success(Device.getDeviceId());
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        this.callbackContext.error("Error");
    }

}

protected void initSDK(){
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                try{
                    String deviceId = mobileDevice.initialize()
                        //hidden sdk code
                    Log.i(TAG, "initialized SDK, deviceId = " + deviceId);
                    callbackContext.success(deviceId);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to initialize SDK", e);
                    callbackContext.error("Error");
                }
        }
    });
}
```

appcomponent.ts:

```
initiateSDK(){
    this.BlueIdPlugin.initializeSDK(
      function(success){
        console.log(deviceId);
      },
      function(fail){
        console.log("Error getting device id")
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: This didn't work mate :( It seems that when I try the function(success) and function(fail) neither of them get called.

Comment: Not sure I can suggest much more without seeing the full code. I would suggest running it in Android Studio and place breakpoints at appropriate points in the Java, and also hook the Webview up to Chrome DevTools for remote debugging and place appropriate breakpoints also in the Javascript.